# Guake default interpreter missing

Tags: terminal

I have compiled tmux, and it is at `/usr/local/bin/tmux`, but it doesn't show up in the list of interpreters in guake. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually just pulling from `/etc/shells`, which is a list of valid login shells.